# Mysql failed to start (free memory is close to zero)

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a cron job for a ruby script that  performs a crud operation in a table every 10 mins, The problem is at the same time the buff/cache and shared are increasing after 5 days the free is close to zero and the mysql is starting to fail.

```
[root@openldap ~]# free -m
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       2048         227           0        1792        1820        1820
Swap:      2048           0        2048
```

- MySQL server has gone away (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError))
- MySQL client is not connected (Mysql2::Error))
- Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError))
- Mysql failed to start (mysql restart is not possible)

Could anyone shed any light on the problem I have here? Sorry if the question is vague, I possibly don't understand what you would need to know. Thanks

Comment: your memory is not low nor close to zero https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ , in fact, you're not even swapping yet (swap used=0), and your available memory is still 1820 (89% from 2048)

Comment: can you check **uptime** of MySQL when you are getting **gone away error**. Same time, check if OOM killer is killing or MySQL is restarting due to memory crunch.

Comment: so you need to check slow queries and tweak MySQL parameters with your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize the problems:

- Free memory close to zero
- MySQL server has gone away (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError))
- MySQL client is not connected (Mysql2::Error))
- Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError))
- Mysql failed to start (mysql restart is not possible)

Answer:

- Free memory close to zero:

your memory is not low nor close to zero (read: https://linuxatemyram.com/), in fact, you're not even swapping yet (swap used=0), and your available memory is still 1820 (89% from 2048)

quick explanation: linux (and even windows) will fill it's empty RAM space with disk cache. those cache can (and will automatically) be deleted when you need more space. see `available` field (free + buffers/cache) instead for how many "free" memory you have.

- MySQL server has gone away (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError))

I assume your script is always running in background (or foreground) rather than using cron, and you open the mysql connection when script starts and then reuse the connection, e.g.:

```
# pseudocode
conn = OpenMySQLConnection(host,user,pass,db)
while true {
  conn.query(sql)
  sleep(10 minute)
}
conn.close()
```

This kind of code will make mysql server to close it's connection with timeout as it's reason since you're opening a connection, do a query, then NOT DOING ANY QUERY FOR 10 minute. In mysql's default . Instead, you can try:

```
# pseudocode
while true {
  conn = OpenMySQLConnection(host,user,pass,db)
  conn.query(sql)
  sleep(10 minute)
  conn.close()
}
```

I have personally experienced this "mysql server gone away" error on my project that have IoT device opening (and not closing for very long time) mysql connection. When I changed my code from `open-loop-sleep` to `loop-open-query-close` like above it solved my problem.

Other cause (I think not very likely) is listed here: https://matomo.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_183/

- MySQL client is not connected (Mysql2::Error))

I suspect that when mysql server closed it's connection, you will get `MySQL client is not connected (Mysql2::Error))`, while this error `MySQL client is not connected (Mysql2::Error))` happened when you try to execute query on closed mysql connection

- Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError))

I suspect this error is another variant of above error. See if my proposed solution fixes them all.

- Mysql failed to start (mysql restart is not possible)

Please check your service log (e.g. for distro with systemd: `systemctl status mysqld`, `journalctl -xe`, `service status mysqld`) for mysql error message and post it in your question.